# Список java процессов

Tags: java, tomcat, linux

java грузит почти половину процессора. Интересует, можно ли как-то узнать список запущенных в java процессов. Перегружал tomcat - не помогает.

Comment: Можно javamelody это подключить https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/.

Comment: Почитайте, может, поможет: http://habrahabr.ru/post/153135/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Подключаемся к процессу JVM с помощью инструментов jconsole или jvisualvm. Получаем возможность online видеть все потоки.
2. Делаем дамп потоков процесса JVM с помощью утилиты jstack (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html). Получаем информацию обо всех потоках на момент получения дампа.

P.S. Грузит половину процессора не Java, а исполняемый код приложения. Посмотрите, где больше всего времени проводит JVM, в потоках, исполняющих логику или в потоке GC. Посмотрите на график работы GC. Не слишком ли часто запускается сборщик и много ли памяти он освобождает каждый раз? Включите логирование GC (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#DebuggingOptions). Не слишком ли много времени занимает сборка мусора? Далее делайте вывод о том, кто в основном потребляет CPU - основная логика или GC. Оптимизируйте самую ресурсоемкую часть. Повторяйте процесс итеративно до достижения необходимого результата.

P.P.S. Еще есть Java Mission Control. Но сам не пробовал.